# How a server use Next.js to generate a full document to send to the client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Next.js is one of the most confusing technologies for me, i can't understand how it works on the server, how a server knows we need to achieve server side rendering with  files created by `Next.js` in the build time?

I understand the client part, but how a server know that we need to achieve server side rendering after deploying the website files created by Next.

What is the difference between a React project created without `Next.js` in which the server send an empty HTML document in response to a client request, and a React project created with Next.js in  which a server will send a full document to the client??

Answer (score 1):

> how a server knows we need to achieve server side rendering with files created by Next.js in the build time?

Have you taken a look at the [Next.js server-side rendering documentation here?](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering). There is [more about static generation here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages).

Also for more on server-side rendering, [check out this site](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-server-side-rendering)

> What is the difference between a React project created without Next.js in which the server send an empty HTML document in response to a client request, and a React project created with Next.js in which a server will send a full document to the client??

Not entirely sure with the wording here, but if you are asking what Next provides, it is a framework that will give you [everything listed on their landing page](https://nextjs.org/) that you would have to code up or figure out otherwise. They provide a quick way to wrap up and generate production-ready files to deploy.

Comment: I read the documentation before asking the question, yes the whole docs talk about creating the production ready files, but we want a server in the backend to serve these files, isn't it??..so what happens with these files on the server with each request, SSR depend on creating files each time a request reach the server, my problem is here, in normal websites we need to serve the static files to the client as it is, HTML, CSS, JS, but in SSR, it is different , we need to populate html and create a full document to send to the client, how this happens on the server?

Comment: @CodeEagle Next.js server server-side renders the HTML page and sends that to the client (in addition to the JS files needed for hydration/client-side navigation). You can achieve that with a regular Node.js server + React.js too, it's not exclusive to Next.js. Next.js just bundles it into a easy-to-use framework.